# NodeJS: Как версионировать СВОЙ пакет

Tags: node.js, контроль-версий, node-modules

Если набрать в поисковике "NodeJS версионирование", то будут гигабайты информации о том, каким правилам подчиняется шифр версии, как установить нужную версию сторонней библиотеки и так далее, но совершенно ничего - о том, как увеличить версию своего собственного пакета. Надеюсь, благодаря Вашим замечательным ответам эта проблема будет решена.

Comment: Вы  пакет NPM имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Дмытрык, да, npm.

Comment: Я меняю ручками: захожу в `package.json` и меняю...если речь про `npm publish`